# How to get signature list from PGPPublicKey using Bouncy Castle library?

Tags: bouncycastle, openpgp

I have a PGPPublicKey object. I want to get a list of all signatures(with UserId, email Id, trust level for each singature) associated with it using Bouncy Castle API. I tried but couldn't get it. If anyone has an example link or knows which method to use to get it, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used these classes but I thought it might be helpful to post some resources.

It looks like the Bouncy Castle OpenPGP releases include [some examples](http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Security/Bouncy-Castle/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/Catalogexamples.htm).

I recommend using these examples to solve your problem. Specifically, it looks like you will need to use `PGPSignatureList` and `PGPSignature` classes which are utilized in the examples. However, I don't see `emailId` in any of the classes.

- [SignedFileProcessor.java](http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Security/Bouncy-Castle/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/SignedFileProcessor.java.htm): A simple utility class that signs and verifies files.
- [DetachedSignatureProcessor.java](http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Security/Bouncy-Castle/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/DetachedSignatureProcessor.java.htm): A simple utility class that creates seperate signatures for files and verifies them.

Also, http://www.bouncycastle.org/documentation.html suggests the following.

> Finally there are also code [examples](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-Cryptography-with-Java.productCd-0764596330,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html) from [Beginning Cryptography with Java](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/redirect?path=ASIN/0764596330&link_code=as2&camp=1789&tag=bouncycastleo-20&creative=9325) which demonstrate both the use of the JCE/JCA and also some of the Bouncy Castle APIs such as for certificate generation, CMS and S/MIME. Note: the book was written to cover J2SE 5.0, while many of the examples will work with earlier JDKs, some will not compile if you are not using J2SE 5.0 or later.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I posted same question in other link also and got some clue. Please read below link   

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625474/does-pgp-signauter-contains-signer-userid